# Why is this query so slow?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have tables FOO and BAR.  FOO has a foreign key to BAR's PK.

When I execute the following query it takes several seconds.

```
select foo.name, foo.description, bar.quadrant from FOO, BAR
where FOO.BAR_ID = BAR.BAR_ID
```

Here is my explain plan:

```
OPERATION        OBJECT_NAME     OPTIONS     COST 
SELECT STATEMENT                                 39 
 HASH JOIN                                       39 
  TABLE ACCESS   BAR             FULL            2 
  TABLE ACCESS   FOO             FULL            36
```

FOO has 6000 records in it and BAR only has 5.  The BAR_ID column is a NUMBER.

This is running on Oracle 10g and it is taking ~3 seconds to complete.  That seems extreme given how quickly it performs other queries.

**EDIT** table defs:

```
CREATE TABLE BAR
 (
    "BAR_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "QUADRANT" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "BAR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BAR_ID")
 )

 CREATE TABLE FOO
 (  "FOO_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    "BAR_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "FOO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("FOO_ID"), 
    CONSTRAINT "FOO__FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("BAR_ID") REFERENCES BAR ("BAR_ID") ENABLE
 );
```

Comment: I am just wondering if you have a FK/PK relation in the tables, then why not make use of the "JOIN" instead of comparing selective columns?

Comment: Can you post the table definitions?

Comment: Do you have any index on FOO.BAR_ID?

Comment: @Mike yes, but the explain plan remains the same unless I explicitly force it using the /*+ INDEX ... */ hint.  Using the index doesn't have any noticeable impact on the speed of the query.

Comment: Oracle's optimizer used to care a lot about the order of tables in the `from` clause.  I'm not sure if it still does or not - try reversing them just to see - for a hash join you want the smaller table to be the driving table, not the larger one.

Comment: If this query is done rarely compared to others, data might be out of cache. This could account for the difference in speed.

Comment: @Donnie: the order of tables only really mattered when the RBO was being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have good statistics?  I created a test case from your DDL and saw this plan before statistics:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |  4996 |  1619K|    10  (10)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |  4996 |  1619K|    10  (10)| 00:00:01 | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BAR  |     5 |   325 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| FOO  |  4996 |  1302K|     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(If you get the dbms_xplan output you'll also see "dynamic sampling used for this statement").

After doing this:

```
SQL> begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'FOO'); end;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> c/FOO/BAR/
  1* begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'BAR'); end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I see:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation                    | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |        |  4996 |   131K|     9  (12)| 00:00:01 | 
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                  |        |  4996 |   131K|     9  (12)| 00:00:01 | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| BAR    |     5 |    40 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | BAR_PK |     5 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                  |        |  4996 | 94924 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 | 
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | FOO    |  4996 | 94924 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: +1 I should've thought of it. I've already seen it. For some reason when data in table changes, Oracle's statistics sometimes don't get updated. Which lead to very bad execution plans. Manual reset of statistics table magically resolves problem.

Comment: Probably 95% or more of Oracle 10g installations are running the standard statistics scheduler job that launches at 10pm and computes stats marked STALE, which are those segments that have had what the optimizer considers significant (~10% I believe) changes since the previous computation.  So, if you had significant changes in table data after 10pm yesterday you might have this issue.  The standard job also uses an internal algorithm for histogram generation, so if the data skew changes after that the optimizer may be misled

Answer (score 2):

There's a bucket load of instrumentation built into Oracle for investigating this sort of issue.

Start with this paper:

http://method-r.com/downloads/doc_download/10-for-developers-making-friends-with-the-oracle-database-cary-millsap

Answer (score 2):

Get a `TKPROF` trace for your query to see what really happens - `explain plan` is just an estimate.

Basically, execute `ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE` command before your query, execute the query, and then `ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = FALSE`. Then find the trace file produced from location determined by `USER_DUMP_DEST` parameter (look into `v$parameter` view). Use `TKPROF` utility to process the raw trace file into more readable format, and examine the results (and post them here, too).

(See [Using SQL Trace and TKPROF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/sqltrace.htm) from Oracle.com for more information.)

Comment: +1 for the good advice. Although I wouldn't issue an "alter session set sql_trace = false" because the cursor can remain open and you'll miss the row source operation in the tkprof file. Issue a "disconnect" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Does the table get frequent updates?

Is foo.description a huge CLOB?

Is network latency making it seem like the query is taking a long time?

Are these tables really complex views?

Were the tables once very large and have since had lots of data deleted?

Comment: 1) No, foo is refreshed once nightly but bar never changes 2) No, varchar 3) no, other queries are running much more quickly even when they are doing more joins between larger tables 4) no, they are tables 5) no, foo typically has one or two inserts a night, and possibly a few updates, but no great changes in size

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember, Oracle will see this as a simple join that will ignore the indexes. The basic idea is that because you are not limiting the data in either table and just joining them together, it thinks that a full table scan will work better. If the foo table has null in the bar_id column for several rows, then you may want to use the index hint.

As an example, if you run the query based on a single bar_id, the explain plan will likely use the indexes as expected. Without the index it will do a full scan on the bar table, because it is very small, and a full scan on the foo table because you are not filtering out any values for bar_id.

One last note is to make sure you update statistics on the tables and indexes. This would be important for a sparse index as Oracle may realize the index can significantly change the cost of the query.

Answer (score 0):

It is very reasonable to make a full table scan to FOO table, the table has 4996 row and you right a query that you ask oracle to "Send all the Foo records along with their bar.quadrant"